# "npm install express-react-views" result in access error

Tags: node.js, express, npm, reactjs

I want to install express-react-views in Ubuntu 14.04 locally(not globally) but the installation results in an access error--it is trying to access global npm folder.

Anything I have done wrongly or express-react-views requires sudo privilege?

Comment: are you able to install other packages in the same directory without error?

Comment: well, yes, things are express and body parser are installed with no problem

Comment: @JunchaoGu check this http://blog.ricca509.me/fix-those-npm-install-errors-when-not-running-under-sudo-in-osx/